# Moving SVG in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, svg

I have a SVG icon that I want to move.

The problem is that the I am working in a big scale and it is hard to click on the right location on the icon. If I am not clicking precisely on the spot it will move.

[image]

Is there an easy way to change the location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy way to change the icon location without being right on the spot.

You need to select the item and to select the "Copy and Move Feature(s) function.

[image]

Now you just need to drag the icon, the red circle is the new location.

[image]

Now you just double click on the left mouse key and the icon is copied. You can erase the old one and the location is changed.

[image]

Comment: Instead of using `copy and move features`, why not use the `move features` tool - it's the same tool, just click the arrow and choose "move features".

Comment: You are wright! However, I know see that be coping it is much easier to see which location is better.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are in the print layout or right on the map canvas. But if you want to create a map with an svg in there, and you don't want to move manually your svg. you can still select it and move it using the position and size box in item properties. Tha's only accessible when you're in the print layout for map creation.

[image]
[image]